# Does Google Dart support mixins?

Tags: mixins, dart

I've skimmed through the [language documentation](http://www.dartlang.org/docs/spec/index.html) and it seems that the Google Dart does not support mixins (no method bodies in interfaces, no multiple inheritance, no Ruby-like modules). Am I right about this, or is there another way to have mixin-like functionality in Dart?

Comment: you might want to update to the currently correct answer :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm happy to report that the answer is now Yes!

A mixin is really just the delta between a subclass and a superclass. You can then "mix in" that delta to another class.

For example, consider this abstract class:

```
 abstract class Persistence {  
  void save(String filename) {  
   print('saving the object as ${toJson()}');  
  }  

  void load(String filename) {  
   print('loading from $filename');  
  }  

  Object toJson();  
 }
```

You can then mix this into other classes, thus avoiding the pollution of the inheritance tree.

```
 abstract class Warrior extends Object with Persistence {  
  fight(Warrior other) {  
   // ...  
  }  
 }  

 class Ninja extends Warrior {  
  Map toJson() {  
   return {'throwing_stars': true};  
  }  
 }  

 class Zombie extends Warrior {  
  Map toJson() {  
   return {'eats_brains': true};  
  }  
 }
```

Restrictions on mixin definitions include:

- Must not declare a constructor
- Superclass is Object
- Contains no calls to super

Some additional reading:

- http://www.dartlang.org/articles/mixins/
- http://blog.sethladd.com/2013/03/first-look-at-dart-mixins.html

Answer (score 2):

Edit:

The Dart team have now [released their proposal for Mixins](http://news.dartlang.org/2012/08/darts-modest-proposal-for-mixins.html), the original [issue for Mixins was here](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=33).

It's not implemented yet, but in the meantime I've released an extensible Mixins library for Dart which includes a port of the popular Underscore.js functional utility library: https://github.com/mythz/DartMixins